# Google play and app gallery best packagename choice

Tags: android, google-play, package-name, appgallery

I have an android app that's intended for both google play and app gallery , It's one project with 2 flavours , currently i have no user system in my app and i have IAP to enable premium features

Note:

> For the google version of the app i don't let app proceeds until gms exists

> For the huawei version of the app i don't let app proceeds until hms exists

My question is what is the best practice among below that i should follow

1- A user here told me to make package name and keystore to be same for both except **VersionNamePrefix** which means my version name on google be **2.0.0Google** and same for Huawei **2.0.0Huawei** is this an acceptable format to the world ?

2- Make different package name for the stores and also different keyStore?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same package name and keystore for your app to publish it in Google Play Store and Huawei AppGallery, respectively. You can also use the same versionName for both. Of course, you can use the different versionName if you want to release different version of the app in different app store. Some Huawei users with GP & AG devices so if you want to use the same package name and keystore, do make sure to publish the latest versions for both stores at the same time so the AG version won't overwrite any previously GP app and erase the IAP purchase history.

On the other hand, you can use different package name and keystore for Play Store and AppGallery. It is up to you.